# Solving an equation using a list of values for a parameter

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

The MWE below

```
Clear[p, x]
p = -Sqrt[2];
{x1, x2} = x /. Solve[p x^2 + (1 + p^2) x + p == 0, x]
```

solves the equation for the specific parameter $p=-\sqrt2$. How can I specify a list of $p$ values, e.g.

```
pvalues = {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], -1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}
```

and let Mathematica calculate the solutions for each $p$? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of many ways

```
ClearAll[p, x];
pvalues = {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], -1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]};
res = ( x /. Solve[# x^2 + (1 + #^2) x + # == 0, x]) & /@ pvalues
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Update

> if I want to use the output and calculate x1/x2 for each of the list
> pairs, how is this easily calculated?

There are many ways to do this. Here are some but I am sure more can be found. Assuming `res` is the above from the above, then any of these will work

```
(#[[1]]/#[[2]]) & /@ res
(First@#/Last@#) & /@ res
Map[#[[1]]/#[[2]] &, res]
Function[{x1, x2}, x1/x2] @@@ res
Apply[Function[{x1, x2}, x1/x2], res, {1}]
```

Each of the above commands gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Follow up; if I want to use the output and calculate x1/x2 for each of the list pairs, how is this easily calculated?

Comment: @mf67 fyi, updated to answer your comment

Answer (score 3):

`Table` is convenient.

```
Clear[sol];
pvalues = {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], -1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]};
sol = Solve[p x^2 + (1 + p^2) x + p == 0, x]
x/.Table[sol, {p, pvalues}]
Table[(x /. sol[[1]])/(x /. sol[[2]]), {p, pvalues}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `SolveValues`:

```
Map[Composition[SolveValues[#, x] &, # == 0 &, Function[{p}, p x^2 + (1 + p^2) x + p]], pvalues]
```

[image]

Or using `SolveValues` and `Thread`:

```
SolveValues[#, x] & /@ Thread[Function[{p}, p x^2 + (1 + p^2) x + p] /@ pvalues == 0]
```

[image]

Or more compact:

```
SolveValues[#, x] & /@ Function[{p}, p x^2 + (1 + p^2) x + p == 0] /@ pvalues
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
List /@ Thread[Rule[p, pvalues]]
```

generates the following rules:

$\left\{\left\{p\to -\sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{p\to \sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{p\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\},\left\{p\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}\right\}$

Each of these values for `p` can be applied to the equation:

```
Clear[x, p];
sol = x /. Solve[p x^2 + (1 + p^2) x + p == 0, x] /. 
  List /@ Thread[Rule[p, pvalues]]
```

$\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\},\left\{-\sqrt{2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$